# Dynamic serialisation in spring using JsonFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization, pojo

I am trying to dynamically serialize a given POJO in spring boot 2.
My use case is, I have a very big model file and I want to retrieve only a subset of fields. The approach I found on the internet is using @JacksonFilter i.e annotate a POJO with @JsonFilter and use that filter name while serializing.

Below is the code sample

```
@JsonFilter("myfilter")
class Resource1{
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  Address address;
}

class Address {
 String addr1;
 String addr2;
 String zipcode;
}
```

And when serializing, if I want only firstname I do this

```
SimpleFilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider();
filterProvider.addFilter("myfilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("firstName"));

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setFilterProvider(filterProvider);
mapper.writeValueAsString(resource1_instance); // Resource 1 instance
```

Now for eg I want to filter another POJO I need to declare JsonFilter for that given class and this repeats for any given POJO.

My concern is, in order to dynamically serialize only subset of fields, for every given POJO we need to add @JsonFilter("suitable_name") and serialize it.

Is there a way to declare a generic @JsonFilter and reuse it just like the inheritance concept.

If I use @JsonIgnore that would be static and fixed.

My requirement is if a model has v,w,x,y,z attributes and I request only x,y attributes at run time, a generic filter that would serialize only x,y attributes of POJO and give me back

Any suggestion on this would be of great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into @JsonView

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic filtering of simpler use cases i wrote an addon for jackson to use antpath style filtering. It should be exactly what you search.

https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter

Comment: Hi, I went through your plugin. Can you please tell the approach how it works and also is there Gradle dependency for the same?

Comment: It pretty much works like the @JsonFilter annotation just that you can define the filter properties dynamically. Gradle is supporting maven dependencies i think, but i have never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can dynamically decide and create a generic filter.

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().setFailOnUnknownId(false).addFilter("CustomerFilter",
                SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("customerId"));
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filters);
        String writeValueAsString = writer.writeValueAsString(customer);
        Customer resultCustomer = mapper.readValue(writeValueAsString, Customer.class);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(resultCustomer);
```

In above code snippet at place of creating filter you can pass set collection as a input.check below snippet
Accept set as a method input which contains sometime x,y and sometimes w,x based on your requirements.

```
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().setFailOnUnknownId(false).addFilter("CustomerFilter",
                    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(set));
```

Comment: This solution still needs to put @JsonFilter annotation over your desire class.